# Combine multiple csv files in javascript using filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with 2 csv files in D3 and I want to combine them together. `id` and `Grade` correspond to the first csv file and `id` and `status` to the second one. `id` is the same in both files.

To convert the files from string into integers I use something like this

```
 data.forEach(function(d) {
   d.id = d.id;
   d.Grade = +d.Grade;
 });

 data2.forEach(function(d) {
   d.id = d.id;
   d.Status = d.Status;
 });
```

What I actually want is to add `Status` to the corresponding id from `data`. Actually to check if the id is the same and add `Status` as a new column according to the id. Any idea how to do this in javascript?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you make it more specific? Anyway, this library can be helpful: http://www.data-forge-js.com/

Comment: Thanks! for example i have the following data in csv1 id 123, Grade 1, id 345, Grade 4 and in csv2 id 123 , Status "yes" , id 345, Status "yes"...I want to add status to the first csv like  id 123, Grade 1, Status "yes" and id 345, Grade 4, Status "yes"

Comment: Not related to your question, but mind your names: sometimes you write `status`, sometimes you write `Status`... that will be a problem, JavaScript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read and save files in JS is with Node.js. So this is working example written in Node.js and with [data-forge](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-ts):

```js
const dataForge = require('data-forge');

/**
 * "csv1.csv":
 *
 * id, grade
 * 123, 1,
 * 345, 4,
 * 177, 5,
 */
const dataFrameGrades = dataForge.readFileSync('csv1.csv').parseCSV();

/**
 * csv2.csv:
 *
 * id, status
 * 123, 'yes',
 * 345, 'no',
 * 177, 'yes',
 */
const dataFrameStatuses = dataForge.readFileSync('csv2.csv').parseCSV();

/**
 * Merge columns from two CSV
 * 
 * dataFrame1 is left
 * dataFrame2 is right
 */
const dataFrameMerged = dataFrameGrades.join(
  dataFrameStatuses,
  grade => grade.id,
  status => status.id,
  (grade, status) => {
    return {
      id: grade.id,
      grade: grade.grade,
      status: status.status
    };
  }
);

/** Save CSV */
dataFrameMerged.asCSV().writeFileSync('csvMeged.csv');
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for doing that. Supposing `data1` as the first parsed CSV (with `id` and `grade` but no `status`) and `data2` as the second parsed CSV (with `id` and `status`), you can use `find` or `filter` to get the corresponding object in `data2` and copying its `status` on `data1`.

For instance, using `find`:

```
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  var obj = data2.find(function(e) {
    return d.id === e.id
  });
  d.status = obj.status;
});
```

Here is a demo (using `d3.csvParse`, since the S.O. snippet doesn't allow real CSVs):

```js
var csv1 = `id,grade
1,42
2,65
3,17`;

var csv2 = `id,status
2,yes
1,no
3,no`;

var data1 = d3.csvParse(csv1);
var data2 = d3.csvParse(csv2);

data1.forEach(function(d) {
  var obj = data2.find(function(e) {
    return d.id === e.id
  });
  d.status = obj.status;
});

console.log(data1)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

I'm scrambling the rows in both CSVs just to show that the order doesn't matter, but only their `id`.

Comment: Very interesting because here works but when I run my program I get vis.js:442 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: with filter i don't get the error, but status is always undefined

Comment: Please create a Plunker or a Blockbuilder showing exactly how you're doing it.